# How to merge two "strings" with unique values to new String in java? Using converting to arrays or lists

Tags: java, arrays, list

can someone please help me to solve this?
Thank you

```
String a = 1||2||3
String b = 2||4||5

String c = 1||2||3||4||5|| //Must be uniqe
```

Comment: The Java code you provided won't even _compile_.  Can you show us the real code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 1):

Using converting to arrays or lists? I do not know what your mean. but I suggest

```
String a = "1||2||3";
String b = "2||4||5";
String[] arrayA = a.split("||");
String[] arrayB = b.split("||");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arrayA);
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayB));            
System.console().printf(list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.joining("||")));
```